# Example makefile for building simple c project recompiling when headers change

Tags: c++, c, header, makefile

Does anyone have a complete makefile that can do the following:

1. Rebuilds the project if a HEADER file changes
2. The cpp files are listed in the makefile
3. The header files are NOT listed in the makefile
4. The header files are allowed to have different names than the cpp files
5. Some of the cpp files do not have header files

I have seen instructions for figuring out how to make the make tool figure out header dependencies, but none of these instructions provide anything remotely resembling a working example.  A simple example would be as follows: main.cpp C1.cpp C1.h C2.cpp C2.h

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CXX = g++

OBJECTS := main.o C1.o C2.o

all: $(OBJECTS)

%.o : %.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -Wall -MMD -c $< -o $@

-include *.d
```

**EDIT:** As TobySpeight points out, this won't work if you build an object file, rename or delete one of the prerequisite source or header files, then try to rebuild the object file; the `.d` file will still require the missing file, and the build will fail. I neglected to include lines to deal with that case:

```
%.h: ;
%.cpp: ;
```

(This is effective, but crude. The more precise approach is to put some sed commands in the `%.o` rule, so as to add specific null rules to the `.d` file, one for each prerequisite, but the sed commands are ugly, and the approach above is good enough for almost all cases.)

Comment: I think you mis-wrote that: should your rule be `%.d: %.cpp`?  I'd also be wary of including `*.d` rather than `$(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)` or whatever, as the former is prone to breaking when you rename/remove sources.

Comment: @TobySpeight: I can tell you didn't test it.

Comment: Yes, of course I tested it.  That's how I know that when you remove and/or rename a header, you get stuck with a dependency file that still references the removed header, whereas if you generate dependencies explicitly, they are regenerated before the makefile is considered fully read.  You should at least have `$(RM) *.d` in your `clean` target, to give some sort of last-resort recovery.

Comment: @TobySpeight: **I apologize.** I omitted an important part of my solution, then neglected to test it properly and *accused you of that mistake.* I will edit my answer and give a proper reply...

Comment: @TobySpeight: I did not mis-write the main rule, `%.o: %.cpp` is what I intended. The edit I've just made to my Answer takes care of the rename/remove problem-- which is a problem for `include $(SOURCES:.cpp=.d)` too. Also, giving a rule for `%.d` causes Make to reinvoke itself whenever something has changed (sometimes with a warning), which is an inefficiency and a nuisance. I didn't mention a `clean` rule (`$(RM) *.d`) in part because the last resort is almost never necessary with this approach (and because I like to keep my answers short, and because 'rm *.d` is easier than `make clean`).

Comment: Does using `-MMD -MP` solve the problem with renaming or deleting headers, without any crudeness or sed? It seems to work for me but I don't know if there is some subtle difference I'm not getting. "This option instructs CPP to add a phony target for each dependency other than the main file, causing each to depend on nothing. These dummy rules work around errors make gives if you remove header files without updating the Makefile to match."

Comment: @Karu: Yes, I think it does exactly that. What's more, I have that in some of my old makefiles, but I'd forgotten about it. Time for me to revisit the basics...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use CMake for this. Everything you need to write is:

```
add_executable (exec main.cpp C1.cpp C2.cpp)
```

Comment: `cmake` is not `make`, and a `cmake` file is not a `makefile`