# How to pass target stem to a shell command in Makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I'm writing a static pattern rule to generate a list of dependencies for targets matching a pattern. The dependencies are generated through a shell command (the file content gives information about the dependencies). Here's an example of the explicit rule:

```
f1.o: $(shell gendep src/f1/f1.source)
    ... (some compilation command here) ...
```

While this works, I do not want to rewrite it for each new target since I'm maintaining the same file structure. My attempt at static pattern rule was like so:

```
%.o: $(shell gendep src/%/%.source)
    ...
```

I'm having trouble passing the stem (matched pattern for %) to the shell command. The shell command interprets it literally and operates on src/%/%.source, which of course doesn't exist.

I suspect there is way of passing the stem to the shell command but I don't seem to find it. Any experts here might be able to help me? Sorry if this is a newbie question (I'm indeed one).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do is difficult, because ordinarily Make will expand the `$(shell ...)` directive before running any rule, or even deciding which rules must be run. We can retard that by means of [Secondary Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion), a slightly advanced Make trick:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

%.o: $$(shell gendep src/$$*/$$*.source)
    ...
```

There are also [other methods for automatic dependency generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871426/example-makefile-for-building-simple-c-project-recompiling-when-headers-change/21873648#21873648).

Comment: I did try that but it doesn't work. For example, when I try $(shell gendep src/$*/$*.source), I receive an error (thrown by gendep) that it is looking for src//.source.source. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @dkn37: I'm sorry, I read your question in a hurry and I thought you were referring to shell commands in the body of the rule. I'll revise...