# Confused about "-include" pattern rule in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

`A1_SRC` and `A2_SRC` define the source C codes that I would compile. `A1_SRC` and `A2_SRC` share the same headers `const.h` and `var.h`. I attach my Makefile below:

```
EXEC=../bin
OBJ=../obj

CC=mpicc
CFLAGS=-O3 -Wall -traceback
LFLAGS=-lm -lfftw3 -lstdc++ -lmpi

$(OBJ)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $*.c > $(OBJ)/$*.d

A1_OBJ = $(A1_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ)/%.o)
A2_OBJ = $(A2_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ)/%.o)

A1_SRC = \
        test.c \
        alloc.c \
        func.c

A2_SRC = \
        test1.c \
        test2.c

A1: $(A1_OBJ) const.h var.h
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A1_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A1

A2: $(A2_OBJ) const.h var.h
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A2_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A2

all: A1 A2

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJ)/*.o $(OBJ)/*.d $(EXEC)/*

install: clean all

-include $(A1_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d) $(A2_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d)
```

Traditionally, in a simple way, we define a pattern rule to compile `.o` files from `.c` codes. In this Makefile,

`$(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@`, `A1_OBJ = $(A1_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ)/%.o)`, `A2_OBJ = $(A2_SRC:%.c=$(OBJ)/%.o)`

can realize this goal. The next step is to perform linking to generate executable file, which is realized by

`$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A1_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A1`, `$(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A2_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A2`

However, I don't understand why it also compiles the so-called *dependency files* using `$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -MM $*.c > $(OBJ)/$*.d`? And then the Makefile does not use these `.d` files until the last line `-include $(A1_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d) $(A2_OBJ:$(OBJ)/.o=$(OBJ)/.d)`... What does the last line mean and how it is related to the `.o` files?

Also, in this pattern rule:

```
A1: $(A1_OBJ) const.h var.h
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(A1_OBJ) -o $(EXEC)/test_A1
```

why do we need two lines? I can't figure out why we should put the first line `$(A1_OBJ) const.h var.h` here?

I expect experienced programmer could help answer my questions. It would help more people who have the same doubt as me find a solution.

Comment: The `-include` directive means "try to include the file(s) named if they exist; do not generate an error if they do not exist".  The `-MM` option causes GCC to create the `xyz.d` file for the `xyz.c` source.  The next time you run the build, the compiler will read the `xyz.d` file(s) and will then check the dependencies.

Comment: I recommend you read https://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ and see if it provides any helpful insights.

Comment: I don't know if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13441510/1256234) helps; it references the same material from MadScientist with regards to the `-include`.  Also, you might want to put your `all` target above `A1` and `A2`, or `make` without any arguments will only make `A1`.